# /bin/sh: jlink: not found. command '/bin/sh -c jlink' returned a non-zero code: 127

Tags: dockerfile, jlink, azul-zulu

the dockerfile used -

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11 as jdk

RUN jlink \
    --module-path /usr/lib/jvm/*/jmods/ \
    --verbose \
    --add-modules java.base,jdk.unsupported,java.sql,java.desktop \
    --compress 2 \
    --no-header-files \
    --no-man-pages \
    --output /opt/jdk-11-minimal

FROM alpine:3.10
ENV JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-11-minimal
ENV PATH=$PATH:/opt/jdk-11-minimal/bin
COPY --from=jdk /opt/jdk-11-minimal /opt/jdk-11-minimal
```

why jlink can't be found in azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is jlink is not on the PATH so can't be found.

If you change the RUN line to

```
RUN /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11/bin/jlink
```

then it can be found.

However, you still have an error using the wildcard in the module path.  Change this to

```
--module-path /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11/jmods/
```

and the docker command will complete successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Please, use `$JAVA_HOME/bin/jlink`.

For historical reasons $JAVA_HOME/bin is not included in PATH, so you need to state it directly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. And it's an issue in the image https://github.com/zulu-openjdk/zulu-openjdk/issues/66

I tried with the version azul/zulu-openjdk-alpine:11.0.7-11.39.15 and it worked